# How to remove repeated tag characters in bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use [Bootstrap Tagsinput](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) with Typeahead on Bootstrap 3, using [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) since it seems the original typeahead was abandoned by Twitter.

I have some weird behaviour, where the characters that get accepted as a `tag` remain in the input field. This creates a very weird user experience. In the example shown here, I typed 'Volunteer' (which was one of the values in the typeahead) and after selecting it as the required tag, the characters remained there, partially visible.

[image: Tag Characters Remaining in Input Field]

This is my code. I am using JQuery 1.12.3, Bootstrap 3.3.6, and TagsInput 0.6.1. The latter two loaded in the footer, together with Bootstrap3-Typeahaed 3.1.0.

```
  <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" data-provide="typeahead" value=""/>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
       var type = ["Donor","Volunteer","Member","Resource","Follow-up","Friend"];
       var elt = $('#tags');
         elt.tagsinput({
            typeahead: {
              source: type
            }
         });
     });
  </script>
```

Do I have something wrong that I am missing that is causing this?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue ? If yes, can you share it, please ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
```

like this one

```
  $('#tag').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  },
  freeInput: false
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tested, I have got the same issue ... any idea

Comment: Thank you @Omar but I found a solution with the selectize plugin, I'm going to post this answer.